# Using Bing Speech Recognition API with node.js Bot Framework on Facebook Messenger

Tags: node.js, botframework, speech-to-text, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I would like to use the Bing Speech Recognition API to convert speech to text when using the audio recording (microphone) button in Facebook Messenger to chat with my node.js chatbot. I have managed to convert speech to text using the instructions from [BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/intelligence-SpeechToText). However, as according the Speech API's [documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Speech-api/documentation/API-Reference-REST/BingVoiceRecognition#Codecs), only the audio/wav codec is being supported. I have checked the content type of the audio recording attachments in Messenger and they are encoded in audio/aac.

I would like to ask you whether there is a nice way to convert audio/aac to audio/wav or if there is some other way to make Messenger work with the Bing Speech Recognition API. Ideally, there is already exisiting node.js code that I could adapt for my existing chatbot.

Thanks and best regards!